# Wine brewing guide

Tags: wine

Is there a good guide for how to brew wine from grapes online? I have searched around and have found very bad and inconsistent instructions. A lot of what I found makes me nervous about lack of sanitation practices or different steps from what another guide tells me. I don't know which one to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started makeing wine, I found this site [JackKeller](http://winemaking.jackkeller.net/index.asp) which has tons of information and recipes on there. I have used this for years as my guide for HomeBrewing. Navigating the site SUCKs, but what do you expect from a guy that makes wine, not web sites.